# Does const reference have external linkage in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker

According to clause 3 of section 3.5 of C++ 1998 standard, a const reference has internal linkage.

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.5) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - an object, reference, function or function template that is explicitly declared static or,
> - an object or reference that is explicitly declared const and neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.

But why multiple definition conflict is generated when compiling the following code?

```
// a.cpp
const int& a = 1;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

// b.cpp
const int& a = 1;
```

And then compile the code.

```
$ g++ a.cpp b.cpp
/tmp/ccb5Qi0M.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `a'
/tmp/ccD9vrzP.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If the const reference is changed to const, as follows

```
// a.cpp
const int a = 1;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

// b.cpp
const int a = 1;
```

It is OK to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference itself isn't `const`, just the object it refers to; so (arguably) this rule doesn't give the reference internal linkage.

It doesn't make sense for a reference to be declared `const`. The C++11 standard clarifies the wording:

> a variable that is explicitly declared `const` or `constexpr` and neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage

with no mention of the nonsensical concept of references declared `const`.

Comment: You mean the wording in the C++ 1998 standard is misleading?

Comment: @spockwang: I don't know about "misleading", but it's certainly confusing, and has now been clarified.

Comment: Does anyone have a good example for using such a reference, and wanting it not file-scoped by default?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Isn't the reference a variable in the C++11 standard?

Comment: @spockwang: Yes. But it can't be explicitly declared `const`, so this rule doesn't apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Mike is correct, here is no new thing, just a little tip.

There is reference and the object that referenced to, the object can be constant then comes internal linkage, but the reference itself can never be constant since it has no CV concept(reference was initialized during declaration, then never shift to some object else, I remember GCC complains if you give a constant reference, mean for int const& r = o; although VS was not complaining, that just makes no sense), since the reference is neither constant nor static, then the declaration crosses source files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a program with the *most const reference* ever. It compiles, and links with C++17 ([try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CS9AeCpOKHX0QLnh)):

```
// a.cpp

extern const int& ir;

int main() { return ir; }
```

```
// b.cpp

constexpr const int& ir = 42;
```

As you can see, `ir` can be referenced from another translation unit, i.e. it has external linkage.

Conclusion: global reference variables have external linkage, unless declared as `static` or in anonymous namespace. Also the `constexpr` keyword on references does not make the reference a constant view to the referree ([try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ca0JlwZvsZAlIDwe)).

---

And `constexpr` references are not implicitly `inline`. This is redefinition of `ir` in C++17 ([try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3TK8IyuKWuL4Zpj6)):

```
// a.cpp

constexpr const int& ir = 42;

int main() { return ir; }
```

```
// b.cpp

constexpr const int& ir = 42;
```

If you put `inline` before the declaration of `ir` in both files, it compiles and links ([try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BmrAUtxRVrRvrfvu)).